# Even if "friend class rect" has been commented in square class why it is changing the private variable of rect class?

Tags: c++, friend-class

confused with below program for friend class use, please help me to solve that

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class square;

class rect {
    public :
            rect(int w = 0, int h = 0) : width(w), height(h), volume(w*h) {}
            void set_data(square &);
            int get_width(void)
            {
                return width;
            }
            int get_height(void)
            {
                return height;
            }
            int get_volume(void);
    private :
            int width;
            int height;
            int volume;
};

class square {
    public :
            square(int w = 0, int h = 0) : width(w), height(h), volume(w*h) {}
            int width;
            int height;
            int get_volume(void);
**//          friend class rect;**
    private :
            int volume;
};

void rect :: set_data(square &s)
{
    width = s.width; *// the variables of rect class are private and it shud not allow to change as i have commented "//friend class rect;" the sentence in square class.* 
    height = s.height;
}

int rect :: get_volume(void)
{
    return volume;
}

int square :: get_volume(void)
{
    return volume;
}

int main()
{
    rect r(5,10);
    cout<<r.get_volume()<<endl;
    square s(2,2);
    cout<<s.get_volume()<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    r.set_data(s); *// accessing the private members of the rect class through object of square class*
    cout<<"new width : "<<r.get_width()<<endl;
    cout<<"new height : "<<r.get_height()<<endl;
    cout<<r.get_volume()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As per friend guide lines if we use friend class then it can able to access and modify the private members of its friend class so even though i have commented "//friend class rect;" in square class why i am seeing that the members of rect class has been changed by square class by "r.set_data(s);" this function
In normal condition as per my understanding the private variables of a class can be changed only if it is friend class(so in below output new width and new height should not be changed as I have commented "//friend class rect;" but even though it is commented I am seeing changes of variables of rect class by set_data function so what is the need to use friend class if private members are changed simply by passing other object to any function.

```
    output of the program :

    50
    4

    new width : 2
    new height : 2
    50
```

Answer (score 3):

`set_data` is a method of class `rect`. It copies the public data members of a `square` into the private data members of `rect`. Nothing strange about it, and `friend` has nothing to do here. When you call it, you don't modify the private members of `rect` by `square`, you modify them by a public method `set_data` of the class `rect` itself. Taking the new values from a `square` does not mean that `square` modifies them. When you say "modify private members of `rect` by `square`", it means accessing them from a method of the class `square`, which is not the case here.